# UI component not updating accordingly to data change

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular6

I'm trying to get a page made up of 3 components to communicate with eachother using a data service. Namely, I have a Create/Edit component, that's supposed to add events, a "next events" component that's supposed to let me accept/decline events and a Calendar component that's supposed to let me see all of the upcoming events.

My service is keeping an array of events and I want that array to be visible to the other components, and whenever I update an event, that change to be dispatched to all the other components. For that, I'm trying to use Rxjs's BehaviourSubject but I've hit a bit of a wall. Whenever I create a new event, I do all the add logic in the service component but unless I reload the Calendar (view) component, I don't see the new event added.

Service component class

```
 EXPORT CLASS eventService { 
  public Sevents = new BehaviorSubject<AgendaEvent[]>([]);
  private eventsToManipulate;

  constructor() { 
      this.getAllData();
  }

  getAllData() {
    this.http.get(url).subscribe(data => { 
    // here I map the events from the API to the eventsToManipulate 
            array
    this.Sevents.next(eventsToManipulate);
    }) 
  }

  addNewData(event) { 
    this.http.post(url, event).subscribe( 
    {
        this.eventsToManipulate.push(event);  
        this.Sevents.next(this.eventsToManipulate);
    });
  }

}
```

View Component class

```
EXPORT CLASS eventView { 
events = new Array<Events>();

ngOnInit() {
     this.eventService .Sevents.subscribe( element => {
     console.log('this is element', element);
     this.events = element;
    })

}
```

The way I understand RXjs, the Behaviour subject should send updates to all subscribers about the new data as soon as it happens. However, it doesn't seem to be the case with my code.

Before, I would get the desired effect by forcing the components to load the data again and again with event Emiters, but I'm looking for something a bit more slick implementation wise with RxJs

Answer (score 1):

You need to make an `Observable` out of the `BehaviorSubject` to subscribe to the changes.

Try this:

```
EXPORT CLASS eventService { 
  private Sevents = new BehaviorSubject<AgendaEvent[]>([]);
  public Sevents$: Observable<AgendaEvent[]>;
  private eventsToManipulate;

  constructor() { 
    this.Sevents$ = this.Sevents.asObservable();
    this.getAllData();
  }
  ...
}
```

View component class:

```
EXPORT CLASS eventView { 
  events = new Array<Events>();

  ngOnInit() {
    this.eventService.Sevents$.subscribe( element => {
      console.log('this is element', element);
      this.events = element;
    })

}
```

I got something similar working [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-p6y4xz)

Comment: I've tried this approach however the end result doesn't seem to change. I've added a console.log(this.Sevent$) on CRUD operations and checked the properties there. The array that contains the events in the behaviourSubject does change, so the data does get updated, but I still can't see it in the View component. I've also edited the question with more information on what I tried

Comment: Are you sure you added the `$` at the end in `this.eventService.Sevents$` before subscribing ?

Comment: Yeah, it's surely there

Comment: checkout the link to _stackblitz_ in my updated answer

Comment: I did. It looks pretty much exactly like what I have in my project. Right now I'm wondering if it's something to do with the calendar component I'm using, since it's not a standard one.